# MongoGame MouseState not picking up clicks

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I'm playing around with MonoGame and have the following code in my Update function:

```
MouseState state = Mouse.GetState();
if(state.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
{

}
```

I'm just trying to get it to fall into the if statement with a breakpoint in there to confirm it's working, but it never hits the inside of the if.

I am clicking in my game window, all over the window, with the left button and even the right button. I'm on a laptop so I figured maybe it might be something to do with having the mouse pad and a mouse plugged in also, but still had no luck with the pad.

Any idea why it wouldn't be picking up my clicks?

Comment: On first sight I don't see anything wrong with it. are you also sure that it reaches the if-statement as well? Try putting a breakpoint in the top of the if-statement and check if it does check every frame. I also recommend to define the `MouseState state = Mouse.GetState();` inside the `Load()`

Comment: Yes, it is hitting the if statement with every Update.

Comment: try with directly accessing method `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Mouse.GetState();` or take latest MonoGame version.